# PCA and demeaning

Tags: pca

Suppose I give a test to many students. I record their performance in each question ( a score) and create a set of variables: the responses of students to each question, so that the scores for each question is a variable. I then wish to do principal component analysis on these variables to find the common components.

Two natural common components are the ability/knowledge of the student versus the complexity level of each question (let's assume both exist in the data). Since the complexity of each question is not a very interesting factor, I wish to eliminate that factor from the start.

My intuition is that by demeaning each variable before doing PCA (or stacking the variables, running a regression on question fixed effects, and saving the residuals), the complexity factor is eliminated by definition because the complexity factor varies across questions but not across individuals within each question. Therefore, removing the mean differences across questions removes the underlying factor.

Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks Aksahal. What is the problem with my approach so that I understand?

Comment: there's no problem, but it seems you're trying to measure ability and knowledge, which are difficult to measure. in SEM framework you explicitly model them as latent, then create instruments such as your tests. you can measure how good are the instruments etc.

Comment: btw, you usually de-mean before PCA. PCA is essentially a rotation, so it helps to have the data de-meaned before turning the coordinates

Comment: yes, it is true that measurement is an issue and it is also true that we usually demean the data. but I am interested in this from a theory point of view, so I do not care so much about the measurement issue. I want to understand whether, by definition, the fact that I demean the data before running PCA implies that I cannot recover the complexity factor (assuming no measurement issues). Is this the case or not?

Comment: if you think that complexity of a question is the mean, then it seems that demeaning across students (the way you do) will remove it from PCA, and you can recover it from means vector alone. however, it's not obvious to me that variance is not impacted by complexity. i found that difficult questions in my tests lead to higher variance too. strong students get As on all questions, while weakling start falling off on more difficult question thus increasing the variance. that's my teaching experience, not systematic study of the subject

Comment: Thanks Aksakal. I understand the phenomenon you describe. But how does variance matter exactly? Suppose scores $s$ of student $i$ with knowledge $k$ in question $j$ with difficulty level $d$ follow a data generating process with 2 factors only :$s_{ij}=k_{i}+d_{j}+\epsilon_{ij}$, where $\epsilon_{ij}$ is noise. If we subtract the mean  score of each question $j$ from each $s_{ij}$, so that all variation in levels across questions is removed, by definition the term $d_{j}$ can no longer explain variation in the demeaned variable $s$.  Where does variation enter here?

Comment: the problem is that DGP could be $\varepsilon_{ij}\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2(d_j))$. Although removed $d_j$ from the mean, it's still in the variance. And the variance is what goes into your PCA

Comment: Do you have the following data generating process in mind: : $s_{ij}=k_{i}+d_{j}+k_{i}d_{j}+\epsilon_{iij}$.  ?

Comment: Even without the interaction term you may not have removed the difficulty completely

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, within the PCA framework, what could be a solution to the problem of identifying a factor $k_i$ (knowledge/ability) in a way that proper controls for the confounding effect of difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your DGP is $s_{ij}=k_i+d_j+\varepsilon_{ij}$, and $\varepsilon_{ij}\sim(0,\sigma^2)$. Your variables are answers to questions $j$ and the observations are students $i$. So, we could write this as:
$$s_j(i)=k(i)+d_j+\varepsilon_j(i)$$

Let's look at means:$$\bar s_j=E[s_j(i)]=\bar k+d_j$$
Now we can seethe effect of demeaning: 
$$s'_j(i)=s_j(i)-\bar s_j=k(i)+d_j+\varepsilon_j(i)-(\bar k+d_j)=k'(i)+\varepsilon_j(i)$$
where $k'(i)=k(i)-\bar k$

With this DGP, you accomplished your objective, eliminated question difficulty, that is not interesting to you. It was important that this DGP had no difficulty in the error term.

However, my experience tells me that maybe $\varepsilon_j(i)\sim(0,\sigma^2(d_j,k_i))$. In which case de-meaning above will not work. The reason is that when we plug this into PCA, it effectively handles the covariance matrix:
$$C=cov[s'_j,s'_k]=cov[\varepsilon_j,\varepsilon_k]$$